# Lucene search for item name that exactly matches returns a similar result, when none should match

Tags: content-search, indexing, lucene

We are getting the wrong result returned.

for example, a search for the item named "alumni" returns the item "commencement-alumni-help" when no result should be returned.

```
SearchContext.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>()
    .Filter(s => s.TemplateId == SpecificTemplateId &&
            s.Path.Contains("/Path/to/Website"))
    .Where(i => i.Name == "alumni")
    .GetResults();
```

I have a theory it might be related to tokenizing; however, item names shouldn't be an issue. Even sitecore's documentation indicates that you can directly search for item names.

Comment: just a thought, why don't you add another filter something like this s.Path.EndsWith("/alumni"). May be a slight performance impact but it may work in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Item name (_name) field in lucene/solr is defined as text type, so it is stored as a tokenized value in search indices. So when you search using name, (query will be formed like _name:(alumni)) it will return all items which contains "alumni" in name.

By default, Name/_name is a tokenized field so the result you are getting is absolutely valid/expected.

Comment: I couldn't quite find "_name" in the config file, but I can totally see that being the case. (it's happened before)

Comment: I am sure that you can edit the schema file in Solr to update the type.. But no idea in lucene